# Catching null values on databinding

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

I have a dropdownlist that is populated from an SQL select statement. The select statement filters for items where the 'bit' is set to false and the items, although still in the database are hidden.

My problem is; when an item is out of stock or hidden (bit = false) the user may still have items that are now hidden so it throws an error. How and where can I catch this,  show the original item or set the value to default?

```
protected void GradeDropDownList_DataBinding (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ddl = (DropDownList)(sender);
    var a = ((Label)MyDetailsView.FindControl("GradeLabelEdit")).Text;
    a = a.Trim();
    if (a != "") { ddl.SelectedValue = a; }
}
```

The select statement;

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="getGrade" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CasesTimeConnection %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT [gradeID], [gradeText] FROM [user_grades] WHERE ([visibleState] = @visibleState)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="True" Name="visibleState" Type="Boolean" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

In page;

```
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:DropDownList ID="GradeDropDownList" runat="server" DataSourceID="getGrade" DataTextField="gradeText" DataValueField="gradeID" OnDataBinding="GradeDropDownList_DataBinding" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GradeDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
</EditItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="gradeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("gradeText") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve LastModifiedDate while retrieving the records and while trying to update the record check the existing lastModifiedDate value with the one you retrieved. If they are different then throw an alert message / display new quantity.

Thanks

Shashi

Comment: Do you have a snippet of code? I'm not too sure where to place that.

Comment: Firstly, May i know if you have a modifiedDate field in your respective data tables ?

Comment: Actually I don't; I have a field visibleState as a bit type which changes. If it is set to FALSE, it is filtered out in the select statement (as above) - I'm asking how to set a standard value when an item is in its hidden state.